# Adobe Flex / as3: How to implement custom drag-and-drop cursors

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, adobe, cursors

Our product team has requested custom cursors during drag/drop operations.  They have provided me with three images to implement:

- **Open-Hand-Grabber.png**: displays when a user hovers over an item that they can drag
- **Closed-Hand-Grabber.png**: item is being dragged
- **Closed-Hand-Grabber-No-Drop**: item dragged over an area where it cannot be dropped

I have embedded these images into the Flex application and I am now trying to implement the desired behavior.

My first thought was to listen to the drag/drop events and set the cursors using the CursorManager.setCursor() method.  This solution seems very code intensive and I feel that there must be an easier way to skin the various drag/drop cursor states.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the various cursor styles available on the DragManager class:

copyCursor

defaultDragImageSkin

linkCursor

moveCursor

rejectCursor

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/managers/DragManager.html

Comment: OK, 80% there.  Added the following to css:

DragManager
{
  moveCursor: Embed(source="resources/images/Closed-Hand-Grabber.png");
  rejectCursor: Embed(source="resources/images/Closed-Hand-Grabber-No-Drop.png");
}

The only thing remaining is the mouseOver cursor...

Comment: Got mouseOver working by handling the mouseOver and mouseOut events on the Lists.  Perfect!

Comment: Do you think you could add the full code as an answer, I have this same problem and can't seem to make it work with what you've posted as a comment. Thanks.